# User control event extension is possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, user-controls, partial-classes

Extend an event in a user control with out changing in the associated class (usercontrol.cs) file, add as separate class in app_code ,is that possible?
Reason:
I am using a CMS (Ektron), so i cant add code in usercontrol.cs file

*code sample:*

user control ascx file

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Usercontrols_WebUserControl" %>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click me" 
    onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

user control .cs file

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("clicked the button");
    }
```

so i need to add some other code (eg: Response.Write("clicked needed button");) to 'Button1_Click' event by creating a new class or any other option to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would handling the button click event on the aspx page suffice? If so then you'd need to expose the event from the control to the page. Have a look at the following post:

[how to add an event to a UserControl in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486377/how-to-add-an-event-to-a-usercontrol-in-c)

Comment: sry that not i wanted, i want is add some logic to Button1_Click with out changing the usercontrol .cs file

Comment: the `Button1_Click` should have been written with a `virtual` keyword; you should derive the usercontrol class and override that method; and then use that derived instance in your aspx page. Else there is no other way...I think. //fingers crossed//

Answer (score 1):

This is possible only if class in main .cs file is defined as [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wa80x488.aspx). Otherwise not.

Comment: as my research partial class method can't override in extended class with out creating new class inheriting the partial class.