# C# make Event to RichTextBox in TabControl

Tags: c#, .net

I make `RichTextBox` in `TabControl`:

```
private void newModuleToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TabPage tab = new TabPage();
  RichTextBox richText = new RichTextBox();

  string promptValue = ShowDialog("Input File Name", "File name");

  tab.Text = promptValue;
  tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab);
  tabControl1.SelectTab(tabControl1.TabCount - 1);

  richText.Parent = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
  richText.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

}
```

and I would to make event `TextChange` to this `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add an event to a UserControl in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486377/how-to-add-an-event-to-a-usercontrol-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the following to `newModuleToolStripMenuItem_Click` code:

```
richText.TextChanged += RichText_TextChanged;
```

Then define the event handler:

```
private void RichText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // add your handling code here  ...
}
```

**Or** you can make your event handler in lambda expression:

```
richText.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
 {
    // add your handling code here  ... 
 };
```